# File only gets written after restarting the Android device

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working in an application that needs to write an `.xml` file. Right now the file only gets filled after restarting the `Android device`, and I do not understand why. This is my code:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {
    val sagaCollectFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".sagacollect")
    if (!sagaCollectFolder.exists())
        sagaCollectFolder.mkdir()
    try {
        val file = File(
            sagaCollectFolder,
            "collect.xml"
        )
        file.createNewFile()
        val factory: DocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        val builder: DocumentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder()
        val doc: Document = builder.parse(InputSource(StringReader(JRPresenter.getFilledFormXml().toString())))
        // Write the parsed document to an xml file
        val transformerFactory: TransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        val transformer: Transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer()
        val source = DOMSource(doc)
        val result = StreamResult(file)
        transformer.transform(source, result)


    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, exception.toString())
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is where I execute the `AsyncTask`:

```
fun saveResult(index: FormIndex, answer: IAnswerData?) {
    formController.saveAnswer(index, answer)
    WriteCacheAsync().execute()
}
```

Anyone knows what should I change in order to fill the file after calling the method and not after restarting the device?

Cheers,

Mauricio

Comment: you're using AsyncTask right? please include where you're executing your AsyncTasl

Comment: Yes, I am using an AsyncTask with only doInBackground method override. It's an application for surveys and the task is getting executed after answering any question.

Comment: include the code where the task is getting executed, the problem might be there

Comment: Done, question edited!

Comment: How do you check if the file is written?

Comment: Shouldnt you close() the stream some where?

Comment: Using the Windows file explorer and pressing F5 in that folder

Comment: Wrong method. Because Windows depends on the media store of the Android device and you did not inform the media store about the new file. Indeed the media store scanner will find your file after reboot.  Use a file manager app on the device instead. Or check self with code.

Comment: Better subject: File only visible with Windows after reboot of Android device.

Comment: @blackapps you were right!
Using the file manager I've seen that everything was working fine. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1):

@blackapps solved my problem:

> Wrong method. Because Windows depends on the media store of the Android device and you did not inform the media store about the new file. Indeed the media store scanner will find your file after reboot. Use a file manager app on the device instead. Or check self with code

Using the file manager I've seen that everything was working fine. Thank you all so much.